Hello, so I'm writing a novel and I want to include a bunch of different skin tones and not seem rude, anyone got skin color names?
So far I have a few names like bastard-amber, latte and caramel skin tone names. Any names would be very helpful!

Welcome to Writing.SE! What research have you already done into skin colour names?

There are already many discussions listed under the related questions links. Objectifying people with food-words is a writing cliché that has earned pushback from readers: https://writingwithcolor.tumblr.com/post/95955707903/skin-writing-with-color-has-received-several

You went for ‘bastard-amber’ to avoid seeming rude?

I attended a diversity sensitivity workshop at a writing conference last year and there was one takeaway that struck me. That is, if you are going to describe the skin tone of one character, do it for all characters. Essentially, don't seem to use one character's ethnicity to add diversity to your character roster and call out their race, assuming that the audience gets that every other character is uniformly another ethnicity, particularly the most likely one in your readership.
On another note, I try to avoid using words that bring to mind commodities like wood (mahogany) or food (caramel)because Black people have historically been viewed and used as products and I don't want to inadvertently reinforce the perception.
It might just be better to find an appropriate way to let the reader know your character's ethnicity in a more straightforward way. "Kara didn't pass the sunscreen to me next, which was almost laughable. Maybe she didn't think Black girls could get sunburned."
The role that ethnicity plays in your story and even the narrative style might further inform how to go about getting these details across to the reader.
Good luck!

This reminds me of a tv commercial for a tooth whitening produce where a school teacher was asking very young children what colors various items were.  The kids all answered with basic colors which little kids would know, like red, blue, yellow, green, etc.
And then she asked the kids what color her teeth and each kid answered with a different and non basic shade like off-white, cream, ivory (which which I guess is always the correct color for teeth), etc.  One kid actually said ecru.  When I worked in the lace business and told adult people on the phone that ecru was an available color they would often ask what did ecru looks like and I would have to try to describe it.
So if some of your characters have white or pale tan skin, I guess you can describe it as off-white, cream, ivory, ecru, or manila.
And if you are writing science fiction or fantasy you can use any shade you want for the colors of some of your characters' skin, eyes, hair, fur, feathers, or scales.
I remember one science fiction story where the people on one planet looked like humans with olive skin, and I assumed they were green.  And years later I learned that olive can be used to describe a brown human skin color, so now I am not certain what color the natives were.
